# How to change width of d3 chart when it expands

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to change width of d3 tree chart when it expands?
Example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/augburto/YMa2y/).
Thanks!

```
    var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
},
width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

Comment: Change the width, then redraw.

Comment: Using the same code that you used to draw it in the first place, except that you only need to modify the existing elements.